# Join three tables and extract unique values from one table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join

I have following tables in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
col1    id    value
1       a      11
2       b      23
3       c      31

col1   id      value
2      b       23
3      c       34

col1   id      value
1      a       11
4      b       45
```

I would like to join the above three tables such that only the value distinct in table 1 show up

The desired output is:

```
col     id    value
3       c     31
```

I tried following query:

```
select * from tbl_1 a
left join tbl_2 b
        on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.id = b.id
left join tbl_3 c
        on a.col1 = c.col1 and a.id = c.id
where b.id is null and c.id is null
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXCEPT` (or `EXCEPT ALL`, if possible duplicates should be retained).

```
SELECT *
       FROM first
EXCEPT
SELECT *
       FROM second
EXCEPT
SELECT *
       FROM third;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXCEPT` operator and `UNION` operator together for preventing duplicates.

[EXCEPT Source](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-except/)

[UNION Source](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/)

**[Working Solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f2c040c6460689e3c81695ec32c406b1)**

```
WITH TAB1 AS (
SELECT 1 AS COL1,       'a' AS ID,      11 AS VALUE   UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS COL1,       'b' AS ID,      23 AS VALUE   UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS COL1,       'c' AS ID,      31 AS VALUE  
),
TAB2 AS (
SELECT 2 AS COL1,    'b' AS ID,      23 AS  VALUE   UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS COL1,    'c' AS ID,      34 AS  VALUE  
),
TAB3 AS (
SELECT 1 AS COL1,     'a' AS  ID,    11 AS VALUE   UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS COL1,     'b' AS ID,     45 AS VALUE  
),
TAB AS (
SELECT * FROM TAB2
UNION
SELECT * FROM TAB3
)
SELECT * FROM TAB1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TAB
```